# Introspecting Template Parameters (Especially Template Alias Parameters)

Tags: templates, metaprogramming, introspection, d

Let's say I have a D template struct:

```
struct Foo(alias pred) {}
```

I want to write a template to introspect what pred is:

```
alias Foo!"a < b" FooLess;
static assert(introspectPred!(FooLess) == "a < b");
```

Is there any easy way to do this?  If so, how can `introspectPred` be implemented?

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I can think of is to define an enum inside the `Foo` type and do some basic introspection. E.g.:

```
struct Foo(alias pred) 
{
    enum string _pred = pred;
}

alias Foo!"a < b" FooLess;
static assert(introspectPred!(FooLess) == "a < b");

template introspectPred(T)
{
    enum string introspectPred = getMember!(T, "_pred");
}

template getMember(T, string member)
{
    static if (__traits(hasMember, T, member))
    {
        enum getMember = mixin("T." ~ member);
    }
    else
        enum getMember = "";    
}

void main()
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to Andrej's solution but a bit more flexible:

```
struct Foo(alias pred)
{
    enum Predicate = pred;
}

alias Foo!"a < b" FooLess;
static assert(FooLess.Predicate == "a < b");

// Other types of predicate work as well
bool bar() { return true; }
alias Foo!bar FooBar;
static assert(FooBar.Predicate == bar);
```

I just tossed the introspection template altogether--you should be able to get what you need by using typeof and the lot on the Predicate member.

Answer (score 0):

```
template introspectPred(X:Foo!T,string T){alias T introspectPred;}
template introspectPred(X:Foo!T,alias T){alias T introspectPred;}
```

Having only the second overload should be sufficient, but DMD disagrees.